# Select Count Distinct the value to get unique data

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

i'm very new in sql and dont have an idea for this even simple one.

table 1 `bos_report_users` contain `user_id,dept,branch_code` table 2 `bos_report_access` contain `user_id,report_id`

i would like join this table so the result should be something like this
`dept | user_id|report_id|`.

this is what i have done and result is not what i'm expected.

`SELECT A.USER_ID,B.REPORT_ID
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT DEPT FROM BOS_M_USERS WHERE DEPT='FINANCE'),BOS_REPORT_ACCESS B ,BOS_M_USERS A
WHERE A.USER_ID='SLTAM'`

kindly assist me everyone. thanks for helping.

Comment: You have no joins in your query. That might be contributing to why you aren't getting the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join is performed through the shared column user_id

```
SELECT
      u.user_id, u.dept, u.branch_code
    , a.report_id
FROM bos_report_users u
INNER JOIN bos_report_access a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 'SLTAM'
ORDER BY u.dept, u.user_id
```

- alias "u" = users
- alias "a" = access

Comment: I got this. but i need to sort them based on department. for example, dept `FINANCE`, there will be 6 user that used the same report id. so i need to know all the report id under finance department. that is my problem now. i'm still figure out using your solution above. tq so much

Comment: Just add/or use more of the columns from either of the tables. I added an order by clause and some extra columns in the select clause to look at

Comment: tq so much. very helfull. this is my final answer. thanks for idea.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT DEPT
 ,u.user_id
 , a.report_id
FROM bos_m_users u
INNER JOIN bos_report_access a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE DEPT = 'CREDIT RISK MANAGEMENT'
ORDER BY DEPT`